# AS3 Loader ignoring .png transparency

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, png, transparency, loader

In Flash CS4, open a new document, change the background colour to something recognizeable (like magenta) and add the following code:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){addChild(e.target.content);});
loader.load(new URLRequest('newsnakelub8.png'));
```

... replacing the .png filename with any you happen to have handy, I grabbed [this one](http://img329.imageshack.us/img329/5742/newsnakelub8.png). Compile the .swf, and join me in a sigh of disapointment - the normally transparent .png now has a white background, not allowing the flash background colour to show through.

Is there a magical 'treatAsPNG24' property that I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: WOW, that's more than a little embarrassing - in my defense, the image that appeared in the preview pane in explorer showed a transparent background - but you're right, I should've opened it in photoshop to make sure. Well, I'm relieved that it's nothing more complicated than that!

Comment: I hate that this is a 'popular question,' since the 'problem' was actually just user error. Maybe it stands as a warning to check and double-check your content before you try to display it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image doesn't actually have a transparent background...

[image]
<sub>(source: [liranuna.com](http://liranuna.com/junk/trans-image.png))</sub>

For your pleasure, fixed image:

[image]

Comment: I was all ready to get defensive and be like, "Uh, yeah, of course it does," but you're right, it really doesn't. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your png. Try opening it in Photoshop and it won't be transparent there either. Try a different one - google it, or publish one from Flash or PS - and it will work fine. (That is, there's no setting to invoke, you just need a proper image.)

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static function getSource(stringURL:String):void {
        currentProcessedURL = stringURL;
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(stringURL);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.load(request);               
    }

    private static function onComplete(e:Event):void {
        try{
            var bitMap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
                (e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).loader.width,
                (e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).loader.height);
            bitMap.draw((e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).loader);
            var icon:BitmapSymbol = new BitmapSymbol();
            icon.source = bitMap;
            standardStringToImage[currentProcessedURL] = icon;      
            getSource(ALL_ARRAY.pop());
        } catch(e:Error) {
            trace(e);
        }           
    }
```

Doing something like this will load Images with white backgrounds. The parameters ,
                    true, 0x00ffffff needs to be added to the BitmapData constructor. I found this thread because I was having white backgrounds loaded with my PNGs, and I knew they had transparent backgrounds. So, hopefully this will help anyone that had the same issue I did.

Comment: +1 for solving the problem that I came here with.  I would guess this is a more common mistake than importing a png that has no transparency in it.  What I've noticed is that if the .png file has transparency in it, that part will be transparent regardless of the `true, 0x0` parameters, but if you blit a larger area than what the .png is, the border will only be transparent with the `true` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's better to teach you how to fish...

If you're using [GIMP 2](http://gimp.org) (free as in beer), just open the image, select *Layer | Transparency... | Color to Alpha* and pick the color you want to be converted to the transparent background.

Comment: "Color to Alpha" sometimes makes stuff worse, I suggest using the "pick color" tool or the magic wand, "Add alpha channel" and then erasing the color in such an image case.